# macOS RTCMTLNSVideoView video content mode

Tags: xcode, macos, webrtc

I'm trying to make RTCMTLNSVideoView available in webrtc for mac to fill the entire container view (`videoContainerView` is the container NSView, `rtcTrack` is RTCVideoTrack)

```
let videoView = RTCMTLNSVideoView(frame: .zero)
videoView.frame = videoContainerView.bounds
       
videoView.makeBackingLayer()
videoView.layer = CAMetalLayer()
videoView.wantsLayer = true
videoView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor
videoView.layer?.contentsGravity = .resizeAspectFill

rtcTrack?.add(videoView)
videoContainerView.addSubview(videoView)
```

It results with video being fit only using one size (aspectFit). I can't seem to make it fill the entire container. iOS webrtc has a property `videoContentMode`. On mac it's missing. How to control the video content mode in this case on mac webrtc? Any ideas appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I can see it's hardcoded inside https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/refs/heads/main/sdk/objc/components/renderer/metal/RTCMTLNSVideoView.m#61

Comment: You can try to access private property `metalView` and change it

Comment: As an alternative you can copy original source to your project, rename class name and change this property

Comment: Find more simple way, updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix:

```swift
if let metalView = videoView.subviews.first(where: { view in view is MTKView }) {
    metalView.layerContentsPlacement = .scaleProportionallyToFill
}
```

Old answer:

As I said in the comments, you have to access private property `metalView`.

To do this, create file named `RTCMTLNSVideoView+Private.h` in your project with the following code

```
#import <MetalKit/MetalKit.h>
#import "WebRTC/RTCMTLNSVideoView.h"

@interface RTCMTLNSVideoView ()

@property(nonatomic, strong) MTKView *metalView;

@end
```

And then you can reassign content mode:

```swift
videoView.metalView.layerContentsPlacement = .scaleProportionallyToFill
```